# C++ CLI structure to byte array

Tags: c#, struct, c++-cli, marshalling

I have a structure that represents a wire format packet.  In this structure is an array of other structures.  I have generic code that handles this very nicely for most cases but this array of structures case is throwing the marshaller for a loop.

Unsafe code is a no go since I can't get a pointer to a struct with an array (argh!).

I can see from [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ReadingStructures.aspx) that there is a very nice, generic approach involving C++/CLI that goes something like...

```
public ref class Reader abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        generic <typename T> where T : value class
        static T Read(array<System::Byte>^ data)
        {
            T value;

            pin_ptr<System::Byte> src = &data[0];
            pin_ptr<T> dst = &value;

            memcpy((void*)dst, (void*)src,
                /*System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::SizeOf(T::typeid)*/
                sizeof(T));

            return value;
        }
    };
```

Now if just had the structure -> byte array / writer version I'd be set!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using memcpy to copy an array of bytes to a structure is extremely dangerous if you are not controlling the byte packing of the structure. It is safer to marshall and unmarshall a structure one field at a time. Of course you will lose the generic feature of the sample code you have given.

To answer your real question though (and consider this pseudo code):

```
public ref class Writer abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        generic <typename T> where T : value class
        static System::Byte[] Write(T value)
        {
            System::Byte buffer[] = new System::Byte[sizeof(T)]; // this syntax is probably wrong.
            pin_ptr<System::Byte> dst = &buffer[0];
            pin_ptr<T> src = &value;

            memcpy((void*)dst, (void*)src,
                /*System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::SizeOf(T::typeid)*/
                sizeof(T));

            return buffer;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the right way to go. CLR is allowed to add padding, reorder the items and alter the way it's stored in memory.

If you want to do this, be sure to add `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout]` attribute to force a specific memory layout for the structure. In general, I suggest you not to mess with memory layout of .NET types.

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe code can be made to do this, actually.  See my post on reading structs from disk: [Reading arrays from files in C# without extra copy.](http://randy.teamkern.net/2009/02/reading-arrays-from-files-in-c-without-extra-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not altering the structure is certainly sound advice.  I use liberal amounts of StructLayout attributes to specify the packing, layout and character encoding.  Everything flows just fine.

My issue is just that I need a performant and preferably generic solution.  Performance because this is a server application and generic for elegance.  If you look at the codeproject link you'll see that the StructureToPtr and PtrToStructure methods perform on the order of 20 times slower than a simple unsafe pointer cast.  This is one of those areas where unsafe code is full of win.  C# will only let you have pointers to primitives (and it's not generic - can't get a pointer to a generic), so that's why CLI.

Thanks for the psuedocode grieve, I'll see if it gets the job done and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Why not create a new array of the same size and initialise each element seperately in a loop?

Using an array of byte data is quite dangerous unless you are targetting one platform only... for example your method doesn't consider differing endianness between the source and destination arrays.

Something I don't really understand about your question as well is why having an array as a member in your class is causing a problem. If the class comes from a .NET language you should have no issues, otherwise, you should be able to take the pointer in unsafe code and initialise a new array by going through the elements pointed at one by one (with unsafe code) and adding them to it.